# Material Form Controls invisible in Angular App

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, material-design, angular6

I just started learning Angular 6 and i'm trying to implement a simple form as a test. 
My problem is : The form controls are invisible, we can't see them, but if i click on the right spot, i can see the elements.

Here are some screens :

**Main Screen :**

[image: Main Screen]

**Elements on click :**

[image]

[image]

The code is nothing fancy, i have a component FormTestComponent, and i created a Module ( MaterialModule )  which contains all Material modules needed that i need. I have no errors in the console.

All the files are available on this git repo :

https://github.com/Shyrro/NewTry/tree/master/ClientApp/src/app

Am i missing something?

Comment: The theme you're using is built for a dark background. The line under the input is actually white, which is why you can't see it against the white background. Are you manually setting the background to white somewhere? You could always use a different theme like indigo-pink.css

Comment: @user184994 Thanks, by changing the themes i was able to see the elements. Strangly enough i didn't set my background to white anywhere else. Thanks.

Comment: The other option to is to add the `mat-app-background` class to the body element, which will apply the dark background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

include `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";` in style.scss

The theme alone works but these are some nice additions :

add `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` :

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

HTML:

```
 <form [formGroup]="basicForm" class="example-form">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="test" placeholder="Just a test">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select formControlName="select" placeholder="Select">
          <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-test',
  templateUrl: './form-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-test.component.scss']
})
export class FormTestComponent implements OnInit {
  basicForm: FormGroup;


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  createForm(){
   this.basicForm = this.fb.group({
      test: '',
      select: ''
   })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

}
```

Comment: I already have the browser animations module, all the modules needed are in the file material.module.ts. 
Thanks anyway, the problem was the theme !

Comment: please accept the solution if it helped so others can find it easily thank you

Comment: i will, i am just testing the other stuff and the form group doesn't seem to work though. I have the error : "formGroup" isn't a known property for form.

Comment: import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

add in Imports []

Comment: Yup thanks, just did and updated the post by the same occasion !